# Is it necessary for the stack pointer address to be divisible by 8 while entering any new function in x86 assembly coding?

Tags: x86

I used assembly programming for arm processor, I observed some crashes in the application while the stack pointer is not divisible by 8.
Is it also necessary for X86 processor to have a stack pointer which is divisible by 8 while you are entering a new function

os-windowsxp/7
arch- 80386 and above

Comment: It depends on what ABI you are using - please tag with OS/platform/architecture.

Comment: Tagged both x86 and ARM? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The x86 CPU will work with the stack pointer not being a multiple of the machine word just fine (except for a possible performance impact) unless the alignment check feature is enabled, in which case all misaligned memory accesses will cause an exception (#AC).

Comment: where can we enable align check feature

Comment: Set EFLAGS.AC (bit 18) and CR0.AM (bit 18 as well) to 1. You can manipulate CR0.AM only from the kernel side, not sure about EFLAGS.AC. See the official documentation from Intel or AMD.